# How to split a string without specifying any separator in asp.net with C#?

Tags: string, c#-4.0

I have a string with 1000 length. I need to split it and assign it to different controls. I do not have any character separator.
Since each string that I am assigning to controls do not contain same length. As of now I am doing it using substring in which i am specifying the length. But its becoming hectic for me as the length is huge.

Please suggest me is there any way to split and assign in simpler way?

Comment: So there's no separator, and the length of each substring is different?

Comment: So just to understand you have a string and an array of lengths for each control?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you correctly, but if you have a string of 1000 length without any separator it's sort of not possible to split it without at least a pattern. Can u show us your string?

Comment: yes..there is no separator and length of each substring is different.Suppose i have a string of length 50 and first 5 character i need to assign to one control another 6 or any other number need to assign to another control..etc..

Comment: just like @Gabriel said, if there is no separator or pattern then it's impossible to split the string without doing it manually. Why don't you post part of the string as an example?

Comment: Can you show us the string, and what you want it to be split up into? Please also show us the code you're currently using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx):

```
 var input = "Some 1000 character long string ...";
 var inputChars = input.ToCharArray();

 control1.Value = new string(inputChars, 0, 100);   // chars 0-100 of input
 control2.Value = new string(inputChars, 100, 20);  // chars 100-120 of input
 control3.Value = new string(inputChars, 120, 50);  // chars 120-170 of input
 ...
```

Or using [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 var input = "Some 1000 character long string ...";

 control1.Value = input.Substring(0, 100);   // chars 0-100 of input
 control2.Value = input.Substring(100, 20);  // chars 100-120 of input
 control3.Value = input.Substring(120, 50);  // chars 120-170 of input
```

You could also do this

```
var parts = new [] 
{
     Tuple.Create(0, 100),
     Tuple.Create(100, 20),
     Tuple.Create(120, 50),
}

var inputParts = parts.Select(p => input.Substring(p.Item1, p.Item2))
                      .ToArray();
control1.Value = inputParts[0];
control2.Value = inputParts[1];
control3.Value = inputParts[3];
```

This makes it much easier to maintain as the number of controls grows larger. You can store this list of 'parts' statically, so it can be reused elsewhere in your application without duplicating the code.

If all the controls the same type, you can do this:

```
 var parts = new [] 
 {
     new { control = control1, offset = 0, length = 100 },
     new { control = control2, offset = 100, length = 20 },
     new { control = control3, offset = 120, length = 50 },
 }

 foreach(var part in parts)
 {
     part.control.Value = new string(inputChars, part.offset, offset.length);
     // or part.control.Value = input.Substring(part.offset, offset.length);
 }
```

Comment: But this could be done using substring also. I want to avoid this manual work for such a large string.

Comment: @Jyothi True. See my updated answer for a more manageable solution.

Comment: Please..is there anyway?? since none of the above avoids manual work.

Comment: @Jyothi Since each string is a different length, you'll have to specify which the lengths of each substring and the control to assign each string to *somewhere*. How and where you store them is important and depends on your particular needs, which is why I've tried to list several options.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get around specifying the information *which* control gets *which part* of the string. Once you have this information (let's say they are stored in a control array `controls` and int array `length`), you can just loop over the string and do a piecewise `Substring`:

```
var controls = { control1, control2, control3, ... };
var lengths = { 100, 20, 5, ... };

int offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
    controls[i].Value = myLongString.Substring(offset, lengths[i]);
    offset += lengths[i];
}
```

Obviously, this will fail horribly if `myLongString` is shorter than the sum of all `lengths` or the array length of `lengths` is shorter than the one of `controls`, but adding some checks for that and throwing a suitable error is left as an exercise to the reader. In addition, the controls must be *compatible* in the sense that they all derive from the same base class with a common `Value` property. If that is not the case, you might have to do a few type checks and casts inside the loop.